# Selecting nodes with XPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xpath, nodes

I am experimenting with selecting nodes with XPath... 
I am using the following code is my iOS app to gather some information about the types of books that I own, whether they are paperback or hardcover:

```
nodes= [rootNode nodesForXpath:@"Collection/books" error:nil];
for (DDXMLNode* node in nodes)
{
    Booktype* bt = [[Booktype alloc] init];
    DDXMLNode *nameNode = [[node nodesForXpath:@"OfType" error:nil]; objectAtIndex:0];
    bt.type = [nameNode stringValue];

   // And lastly, I am adding this object to my array that will be the datasource for my tableView
   [array addObject:bt];
}
```

My Library XML looks like this:

```
<Collection>

<books>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
  <ofType>Hardcover</ofType>
</books>

<books>
  <title lang="eng">Stella Bain</title>
  <price>19.99</price>
  <ofType>Hardcover</ofType>
</books>

<books>
  <title lang="eng">The First Phone Call from Heaven</title>
  <price>12.95</price>
  <ofType>Paperback</ofType>
</books>

<books>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
  <ofType>Paperback</ofType>
</books>

</Collection>
```

So I have 2 paperback, and 2 hardcover books: great. Now the problem is that when load the data into my `tableView` I get 4 total listings for my `ofType` request:

I get a table view that looks like this:

[image]

***How can I go about having only 1 instance of the type?*** So instead of 2 of each i will only get 1 paperback listing and 1 hardcover listing... My intent is to later add another `tableView` that will list all of the books in the selected type of book category.

Please be as specific and detailed as possible in your answer.

Regards,
-VZM

Update: I have tried to implement the following:

```
if (![array containsObject:bt]) {
    [array addObject:bt];
}
```

But unfortunately this is returning the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check it before adding your `Booktype` to `array` as,

```
if (![array containsObject:bt]) {
    [array addObject:bt];
}
```

Comment: I just tried implementing this code, but unfortunately it did not work... I am getting the same result I was getting when I posted the question @Anusha

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [**NSPredicate**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) for this.

Change:

```
[array addObject:bt];
```

With:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.type == %@", bt.type];
if ([[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] count] == 0)
{
    [array addObject:bt];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will give a idea to you...

```
  NSMutableArray *arrayPaperCover = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *arrayHardCover = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    nodes= [rootNode nodesForXpath:@"Collection/books" error:nil];
    for (DDXMLNode* node in nodes)
    {
        Booktype* bt = [[Booktype alloc] init];
        DDXMLNode *nameNode = [[node nodesForXpath:@"OfType" error:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        bt.type = [nameNode stringValue];


        if ([bt.type isEqualToString:@"Paperback"]) {
            [arrayPaperCover addObject:bt];

        }
        else ([bt.type isEqualToString:@"Hardcover"]) {
            [arrayHardCover addObject:bt];

        }

    }
    NSMutableArray * dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // this will be your data source 
    [dataSource addObject:arrayPaperCover];
    [dataSource addObject:arrayHardCover];
```